# Laravel @stack in component

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, components, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade

I've created a tile component in my Laravel app, which is used on several pages to display/link to recipes (note: this is not an angular, vue or react component).

In my tile component I "push" a css file to a stack called `styles`:

```
@push('styles')
  <link href="{{ mix('css/tile.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush
```

In my `head.blade.php` the `styles` stack is outputted:

```
@stack('styles')
```

Every time my component is called/rendered, the `tile.css` file is added to my `style` stack. This works like a charm, my tiles are styled according to my `tile.css` file. The only problem is that the `tile.css` file is added to the `styles` stack multiple times.

Is there a way to prevent/check for double inserts in the `styles` stack, or do I have to manually add the `tile.css` file to every page/blade file on which the tile component is generated?

Comment: isn't there a parent component which calls this one? you can put the style there

Comment: Yeah, push/stack isn't "smart" it's just a way to append content (the push) to a block and output it (the stack). If you're getting duplicate content, you probably want to push to the stack once before you loop through your tile blade.

Comment: Yes, that's my own suggested answer. Adding the CSS files to the parent blade.php file, but if there is a more cleaner way of doing this... Now I have to go through each file, manually add the 'push' code instead of adding it once inside the component...

Comment: @Tomjesch I have the same issue with a custom Dashboard with components that are dynamically selected by the user needing a reallyLarge.js file. While using `@stack` and `@push` the same reallyLarge.js file is added multiple times, but a network inspection indicates that the browser only makes one request so while it increases the html output by another line it's being served multiple times.

Comment: @Azeame True, the network inspector shows the browser only makes one request to the specific CSS file. Though it's unnecessary code in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pushonce` was introduced in Laravel 7.

```
@pushonce('styles')
  <link href="{{ mix('css/tile.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for! In combination with checking if there are any recipes `pushonce` works like a charm!

Comment: @ahinkle But this was tagged for Laravel 5. If you or someone has solution for Laravel 7, ask question and answer one, tagging it with Laravel 7 (or providing in title). This way, maybe in Laravel 30 your solution won't work and what then - someone will add new answer and op will change approved answer to other although original question asked about Laravel 5? Come on.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it's not possible but to be honest I don't see any point to use it.

In fact you usually create multiple SASS files which you concatenate into single file using Laravel mix, so you don't care which piece of CSS need on every subpage. You just have all CSS compiled into single file, so browser loads CSS once only and then use file from cache.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that it's not possible! The reason for my question is that I'm experimenting with loading files (js/css) only when they're needed. I will look into concatenating (and minifying) my code or including the code by hand on the specific pages!

Comment: It can be useful when you have, say, a chart lib which generates random ID on each chart container. Then you can't include your JS in the main file.